# Get user data from mysql database when logging and store in $_SESSION

Tags: php, mysql

When a user logs in to the member's only area I'm trying to pull additional data like their first name along with their log in credentials which is email and password, but can't seem to have the query successfully output the data. It successfully logs in but I can't get anything else passed through into the Session

```
<?php

    session_start();

   @$db = new mysqli("localhost", username, password, table);

   if ($db->connect_errno !=0)  {
       exit;
   }

   $usern = $_POST['username'];
   $passw = $_POST['passw'];

   $query = "SELECT * FROM cf_users WHERE(firstname='".$firstName."' and email='".$usern."' and password='".$passw."')"; 

   $db->query($query); 

    $result = $db->query($query);

    $row = mysqli_fetch_array($result, MYSQLI_BOTH);

    if($row[0]>0)  {
        $_SESSION['email'] = $usern;
        $_SESSION['firstName'] = $row['firstName'];  // Modified after suggestion
        header("location: page.php");
        exit();
    }
    else {
        exit("Login Failed.<br/>'.
       'Please fill them in and try again. <a href='javascript:history.go(-1)'>Go back</a>");
    }

    $closed = $db->close();
?>
```

Comment: just use the values from your $row array, if their firstname is in the database $_SESSION['firstname']=$row['firstname']. Also worth mentioning that your script could be a lot more secure, as it's open to SQL injection, and passwords are stored as clear text - look into encoding them with md5 or sha2

Comment: Another good idea is to create a user object. You could store all information you need in the object and then just save it in a session var.

Comment: I added $_SESSION['firstName']=$row['firstName']. to the code and then <?php echo $_SESSION['firstName']; ?> and it displayed the number 1

Answer (score 0):

You should add the `session_start();` to the beginning of your `page.php` too.
And be careful for that line

```
$_SESSION['firstName'] = $firstName;
```

since `$firstName` is not defined.